# HTML form post with hidden type not working in WKWebview and getting "nil" in HTTPBody

Tags: html, ios, cordova, post, wkwebview

Using WKWebView and facing the issue with HTML Form POST method.

The HTML page has the below code -

```
<div class="mainSection">
  <form class="myform" target="_blank" method="POST" action="https://abc/xyz.aspx">
     <div>
        <input type="hidden" value="UserName" name="userName">
        <input type="hidden" value="memberName" name="member" >
     </div>
     <a>
        <section class="row">
           <div class="small-10 columns">
              <h2>
                  <span>Some Text</span>
              </h2>
              <div>Some Content</div>
           </div>
           <div class="small-2 columns">
                  <span>Some Text</span>
           </div>
        </section>
     </a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Getting "nil" in HTTPBody. Whereas in UIWebView working properly.

What can be the solution? Please help me with this issue.